# Best way to load strings into a cache

Tags: java, list, caching

I am building a couple of methods which are supposed to create a cache of input strings, load them in to a list, and then determine the number of occurrences of each string in that list, ranking them in order of the most common elements.

The string, or elements themselves are coming from a JUnit test. It's calling up a method called

```
lookupDistance(dest)
```

where "dest" is a String (destination airport code), and the lookupDistance returns the distance between two airport codes....

There's the background. The problem is that I want to load all of the "dest" strings in to a cache. What's the best way to do that?

I have skeleton code that has a method called:

```
public List<String> mostCommonDestinations()
```

1. How would I add "dest" strings to the List in a transparent way? The JUnit test case is only calling lookupDistance(dest), so how can I also redirect those "dest" strings to the List in this method?
2. How would I then quantify the number of occurrences of each element and say, rank the top three or four?

Answer (score 0):

You can add known destination at startup and keep adding new strings to cache as they arrive. That's one way. The other way is to cache strings as they are requested, keeping them for future request. In that case your `lookupDistance` should also cache string.

Start by making a small class that contains a Hashmap. The key would be your destination string, and the value can either be an object if you want to keep multiple information or just a number specifying how many times that string is used. I would recommend using a data object.
Please note that code below is just to you an idea, more like a pseudo-code.

```
class Cache {
private Hashmap<String, CacheObject>;

public void Add(string, CacheObject);
public CacheObject Lookup(string);
public CacheObject Remove(string);
public static Cache getInstance(); //single cache
}

class CacheObject {
public int lookupCount;
public int lastUsed;
}
```

In your `lookupDistance` you can simply do

```
if(Cache.getInstance().Lookup(string) == null) {
Cache.getInstance().Add(string, new CacheObject() { 1, Date.now});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a `Map<String, Integer> destinations = new HashMap<>();`
2. In `lookupDistance(dest)`, do something like this (untested pseudocode):

   Integer count = destinations.get(dest);
   if (count == null) {
        destinations.put(dest, Integer.valueOf(1));
   } else {
       count = Integer.valueOf(count.intValue() + 1);
   }

This way, you count the occurences of each `dest`.

1. Go through the Map and find the highest counts. That's a bit tricky. One approach might be:

   List> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.addAll(destinations.entrySet());
   // now you have a list of "entries", each of which maps from dest to its respective counter
   // that list now has to be sorted
   Collections.sort(list, comparator);

The comparator we used in this invocation has still to be written. It has to take two arguments, which are elements of the list, and compare them according to their counter value. the `sort` routine will do the rest.

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> comparator = new Comparator<>() {
    public @Override int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> a, Map.Entry<String, Integer> b) {
        return a.getValue().intValue() - b.getValue().intValue();
    }
}
```

Ok, so we have a sorted `List` of `Entry`s now from which you can pick the top 5 or so. Think that's pretty much it. All this looks more complicated than it should be, so I'm curios for other solutions.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get the code formatting right. Maybe somebody with more knowledge of the syntax can edit this and make it correct. Also, the third point of the list should be numbered "3.", not "1."